# GCM without using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it OK to use GCM without involving Firebase?

As I saw from Google(https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) that, "New Cloud Messaging projects must create a Firebase project". Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes. You could still use the service without (technically) using Firebase.

[Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is the old version for Firebase Cloud Messaging. During that time, it was only required to create a Google Developer Project in order to use the service.

GCM has since become part of Firebase and was rebranded as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). Although the name adds in Firebase, FCM is still a service on it's own, where most of what it is right now, is still based from the old version (of course there are a lot of new stuff by now, but you get what I mean) -- in which case you can still use the service *without* using the other Firebase services.

Creating a Firebase Project doesn't mean you would have to use or it counts as using the other Firebase services. It's just the place where you would see most of the data related to your FCM service.

All users, even the old GCM users, are currently (*strongly*) encouraged to actually import their projects to Firebase Console.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now